# Are most members of the other Stack Exchange communities Stack Overflow members?

Tags: discussion

This is maybe impossible to know, I'm just curious if the majority of other Stack Exchange Community members started as Stack Overflow members?

Comment: I think this answer of mine is related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284133/158100